# SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE 'num+sometext'

Tags: mysql, sql

I am curious to know , how these queries work in database engine. Specially my focus is on line no 4 and 6.

```
1.SELECT * FROM tableName
2.SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE 1
3.SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE 123
4.SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE '2xyz'

5.SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE ''
6.SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE 'xyz'
```

In the above queries 1,2,3,4 are producing same result but 5 and 6 are not producing any result. why? what is diff b/w WHERE '2xyx' and 'xyz'?
How '2xyz' implicitly converted into 2 ?

Comment: Now I am curious, what result does 2 and 3 produce in **sql**? because there is no relation to a field in the table... and you are supposed to see this error (for second line you wrote):  `An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near '1'.`

Comment: i have just checked 1,2 and 3 are produced  same result @KarenAni

Comment: ok, so I guess in MySql it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

The `where` clause evaluates to boolean true (not 0) or false (0) in order to decide if a record is in or out of the resultset.

- Cases 2 and 3 retrive all records because the non zero numbers evaluate to true.
- Case 3 retrieves all records because during the implicit string to number conversion mysql evaluates the string from left to right character by character. As long as as the characters can be evaluated as a number, mysql will take their value. This includes chopping of leading spaces, interpreting plus or minus signs, decimal points, and so on. So, the string `'2xyx'` is interpreted as 2, thus boolean true.
- Case 4 and 5 do not retrieve any records because the strings' leftmost character cannot be evaluated as a number, so the conversion returns 0, thus boolean false.

Unfortunately, the implicit string to number conversion is not really documented in the MySQL manual. Most of the rules, however, can be deducted from the following part in [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html) section of the manual:

> For comparisons of a string column with a number, MySQL cannot use an
>   index on the column to look up the value quickly. If str_col is an
>   indexed string column, the index cannot be used when performing the
>   lookup in the following statement:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE str_col=1;1
> ```
>
> The reason for this is that there are many different strings that may
>   convert to the value 1, such as '1', ' 1', or '1a'.

Comment: Good answer.  Maybe add a doc link to ensure future rep points as well +1.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it's not really documented (at least I could not find any good official description), added what I could.

Answer (score 0):

It is `WHERE <condition>`, e.g. `WHERE col1 = 123`. What you have instead is `WHERE <number>` or `WHERE <string>`, so there is an expression missing.

What would be possible though is `WHERE <boolean>`, and this is what MySQL expects. And as MySQL treats booleans like numbers (0 = false, other numbers = true), it looks for a number.

- 1 and 123 are numbers that result in true.
- '2xyz' gets converted to 2, i.e. true.
- '' and 'xyz' get converted to 0, i.e. false.

So the latter give you an empty result set as the where condition renders false.

Comment: Can you provide a documentation reference for the behavior of string literals as boolean expressions (I can't) ?

Comment: It is an implicit conversion. As there is no comparision operator, the literal must represent a boolean. The string gets hence converted into a boolean, i.e. a number :-)

Comment: but how '2xyz' gets converted to 2? How mysql engine does it?

Comment: MySQL takes the leading digits when converting strings to a number. When there are none, the result is 0.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the catch all rule applies: string is converted to a floating point number (mysql does not really have a boolean data type)

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner Do u have document reference for the conversion behavior of string literals as boolean expression? If u have pls share the reference links.

Answer (score 0):

In statement `SELECT ... WHERE [where_condition]`, in `where_condition` [expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/expressions.html) you can use any of the functions and operators that MySQL supports, in which [string literal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html) is also supported. For strings the comparisons are based on the numeric values of the string unit. When evaluating an expression [type conversion](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html) is also done.

So in above case the **2xyz** gets converted to **2** which is `true` and hence you get all the records. Its like

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE 2
```

and the string **xyz** gets converted to **0** which is `false` due to which you get empty result set. Its same as:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Where having condition value. Mysql any number treat as TRUE value and null or '' treat as FALSE.

```
1.SELECT * FROM tableName -- all record return
2.SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE 1 -- Return true value
3.SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE 123 -- Return true value 
4.SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE '2xyz' -- Return true value because there first character is number

5.SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE '' -- false value return
6.SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE 'xyz' -- false value return
```